# Are JointPositionControllers supposed to wrap angles on continuous joints?

Tags: ros, ros-control, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was expected to be able to give a large position command to a continuous joint and see the joint spin multiple revolutions before arriving at the desired position, instead it appears to be wrapping the angle and sometimes moving in the opposite direction of what is desired.  Is it supposed to work like that?

This is Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04, using Gazebo 2.2.3 - perhaps gazebo is wrapping the angle and the controller needs to look for that event and keep internal track of angle.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197805/are-jointpositioncontrollers-supposed-to-wrap-angles-on-continuous-joints?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2014-11-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harshitsureka](https://answers.ros.org/users/29428/harshitsureka/) on 2017-03-27**:
Hi, were you able to get a solution? Facing the same problem in my setup (Ubuntu 16.04, Gazebo 7). Thanks

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-03-27**:
No I haven't looked into it.  I suspect this needs to be fixed in the source code https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the controller is calling `shortest_angular_distance` on the difference between the current and targeted position (from https://github.com/ros/angles or /opt/ros/kinetic/include/angles/angles.h)

```
ros_controllers$ grep -r shortest_angular_distance
joint_trajectory_controller/include/joint_trajectory_controller/joint_trajectory_segment.h:    Scalar dist = angles::shortest_angular_distance(prev_position, next_position);
joint_trajectory_controller/test/joint_trajectory_controller_test.cpp:  // that it has to wrap when in fact it doesn't. This comes from a call to angles::shortest_angular_distance, which
effort_controllers/src/joint_position_controller.cpp:   angles::shortest_angular_distance_with_limits(
effort_controllers/src/joint_position_controller.cpp:    error = angles::shortest_angular_distance(current_position, command_position);
velocity_controllers/src/joint_position_controller.cpp:   angles::shortest_angular_distance_with_limits(
velocity_controllers/src/joint_position_controller.cpp:    error = angles::shortest_angular_distance(current_position, command_position);
```

angles.h:

```
 static inline double normalize_angle(double angle)
  {
    double a = normalize_angle_positive(angle);
    if (a > M_PI)
      a -= 2.0 *M_PI;
    return a;
  }


  /*!
   * \function
   * \brief shortest_angular_distance
   *
   * Given 2 angles, this returns the shortest angular
   * difference.  The inputs and ouputs are of course radians.
   *
   * The result
   * would always be -pi <= result <= pi.  Adding the result
   * to "from" will always get you an equivelent angle to "to".
   */

  static inline double shortest_angular_distance(double from, double to)
  {
    return normalize_angle(to-from);
  }
```

I think a solution would involve creating a new joint type that doesn't do the the wrapping.

Started an issue here:
https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/issues/261

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0